# How do I remote to my desktop?

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access

I am wondering how I remote into my ubuntu machine from a Windows Machine that is on a different network?

Answer (score 0):

On your ubuntu run this command to install VNC server:

`sudo apt-get install vnc4server`

then run `vncpasswd` to give vnc server a password

run `vnc4server` command to start vncserver

connect from windows with ultravnc or ... and type: UBUNTU-IP-ADDRESS:1

any questions?

this link may help too: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC/Servers